# How to remove Page cached by boost message in view source

Tags: 7, caching

I installed Boost and the page cached by boost will have a line of message at the bottom of view-source.

```
<!-- Page cached by Boost @ 2014-11-08 14:04:46, expires @ 2014-11-09 14:04:46, lifetime 1 day -->
```

How to remove the above line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the 7.x-1.x version of the module (unless you patch the code). You should file a feature request in the [Boost issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/boost?categories=All).

If you want to temporarily patch the code, open the file boost.module, around line 1145:

```
  $types['text/html'] = array(
    'title'           => t('HTML'),
    'description'     => t('HTML output, usually a webpage'),
    'extension'       => 'html',
    'enabled'         => TRUE,
    'gzip'            => TRUE,
    'lifetime_max'    => 3600,
    'lifetime_min'    => 0,
    'comment_start'  => NULL, // <--- set to null
    'comment_end'    => NULL, // <--- this too
    'variants'        => array(),
  );
```

If you would like to contribute a patch, which would be greatly appreciated, the right way to do this would be to modify the boost_exit() function, around line 315:

```
  // Add note to bottom of content if possible.
  if ($_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_start'] && $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_end'] && $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_footer_enabled']) {
    $expire = $_boost['matched_header_info']['lifetime_max'];
    $cached_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', REQUEST_TIME);
    $expires_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', REQUEST_TIME + $expire);
    $note = "\n" . $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_start'] . 'Page cached by Boost @ ' . $cached_at . ', expires @ ' . $expires_at . ', lifetime ' . format_interval($expire) . $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_end'];
    $data .= $note;
  }
```

You would also have to set the default (TRUE) in boost_boost_storage_types(), and to the `$keys` in `boost_get_storage_types()` so that it does the `variable_get()`. Bonus points for also exposing it to the admin interface.